# Is it possible to use custom domain for email with MS Office 365 Home?

Tags: office365

I am trying find out if it is possible to use Office 365 Home to manage my custom domain and email accounts (I need multiple email accounts). Actually looking for the same feature available in domains.live.com (soon to be ended).

Comment: Office 365 Home does not contain an E-Mail service. Are you sure that's what you're asking about? Not Exchange Online?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I needed a Google Apps replacement. So, I searched and found some solutions. I just looked up Exchange Online. It is expensive than Office 365. In the Exchange Online site I saw this line "Exchange Online is available as a standalone service or you can get it as part of an Office 365 plan that includes Office, SharePoint, and Lync. The following table compares the two standalone plans". Doesn't that mean email service is available in Office 365 ?

Comment: It's part of Office 365 Business. It's slightly more expensive (+$2.51).

Comment: After going through so many articles on how to use custom domain with Office 365 Personal, I have come to a conclusion that it is way better to get office365 subscription from your domain/hosting provider. I don't like GoDaddy, but IONOS seems a good provider.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem so I googled and found this in [Microsoft's help pages](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-suite-help/can-i-add-custom-subdomains-or-multiple-domains-to-office-365-HA102818379.aspx):

> You can add multiple custom domains in all Office 365 subscriptions[...]

This help article looks as if it were possible but they only talk about the business versions and Office 365 Home isnt mentioned with a single word - so I continued my research, even contacted Microsoft - they had no idea, but then [I finally found this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-office_install/use-of-own-domain-name-with-office-365-homepremium/77d72795-dd77-4f08-a2f5-a273603453eb?page=2):

> yesterday I called MS Support and the support engineer was discussing
>   in the background with a colleague. Then he said that it's possible to
>   use own domain with O365 Home... I just had to create a new account
>   with my personal email adres/domain... after that I could order O365
>   and configure it with my own DNS domain name. Then after changing MX
>   records with my hosting provider this would work for me.
>
> anyway...  I tried this anyway... I created a new account with my
>   personal domain... then I ordered Office365Home hooked up to my paypal
>   account....but in the end... no options for me to configure this.
>   So I called back.... I got the same engineer... but then he said.. sorry, I don't have enough technical expertise, cause I'm a sales
>   guy.... strange, because I tried to get tech help... The guy gave me a
>   phonenumber to local (Belgium) Microsoft Tech support.... so I called
>   the number. Then I got first or second line tech support on the line,
>   so I expained the situation and the proposed option from his
>   colleague. But I got a negative response.
>
> No, sir, O365 Home does not allow you to use your own domain... why should it, there are not so many families using their own DNS
>   domain, sir...
>
> DUHH !!! What ? I don't understand their response... I times like this... people make their own family website... use a personal
>   domain....   so I believe this is really a stupid reaction from a
>   Microsoft Tech guy. Probably he has his own domain at home  ;-) The
>   only option is to choose for O365 Small Business and pay a lot more,
>   because you need to pay for every user... every family member... so
>   that would cost me at least 200€-250€ yearly.... please get serious !
>   so I give up.... Also Google Apps only has a business solution... also
>   around 200€ yearly. Office365 Home... useless   -> go for Office365
>   SMB... 2expensive ! I'll try again when Microsoft grows up and gets
>   serious.

After all I don't think it is possible, I also found some forum posts and comments in blogs and they all say it isn't possible.

Comment: Such a great shame. They used to let anyone add a custom domain completely for free.  I don't think it's a stupid conclusion to come to though, most families won't have a custom domain, but if you're paying anything for email I would think that it makes sense to have this option as standard because it's a step up from having `outlook.com`.  I'm talking about back in the day when it was `hotmail.com` which was a bit of a stupid and non-professionally viewed domain.

Answer (score 2):

As of January 2020, this is [now possible](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-a-personalized-email-address-in-microsoft-365-75416a58-b225-4c02-8c07-8979403b427b) with a subscription to Microsoft 365 Personal or Family Edition (formerly Office 365), but according to Microsoft you are required to purchase your domains with (or transfer them to) GoDaddy. I have found sources that claim this is possible with other domain registrars, with some users reporting success, but Microsoft maintain that this is only possible via GoDaddy.

Comment: Nice! Seems like you just need to set that _domainconnect CNAME listed in that page below.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Office365/comments/ft15pk/use_personalized_domain_with_outlook_and_office/